# MVC2 Model Validation - Require at least one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a model, EventSearch defined and I'm stumped on how to create a validator that will require at least one field to be filled for the model to be considered valid. It seems to me this will either be a model annotation or I could annotate each property as belonging to a group of "Require At Least One". Anybody run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these links on how to create custom data annotations by extending from the ValidationAttribute class:

[Custom model validation of dependent properties using Data Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280539/custom-model-validation-of-dependent-properties-using-data-annotations)

[Custom Validation Attribute MVC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114594/custom-validation-attribute-mvc2)