# ASP.NET Data Annotation: How to validate a List of string?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, validation

Data annotation to validate an inbound model in MVC:

```
public class ValidNumber
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

Would I need to create my own class to validate a `List<string>` or can I do something like this?  What code could I write in C# to add a Regex validator for a list of string?

```
public class ValidNumberList
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public List<string> numbers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you can inherit from ValidationAttribute Class and implement your own IsValid Method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is explained how to create custom attribute and implement what you need [Custom Validation Attribute MVC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114594/custom-validation-attribute-mvc2)