# Custom ValidationAttribute, not showing at member

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I'm working on a somewhat legacy smelling MVC2 project, where someone tried to do a ConfirmMustMatch validation attribute. I fixed it using this [PropertiesMustMatchAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114681/571536), but it shows up only in ValidationSummary. That is obviously because the ModelStateError's key is empty string. So, I looked for the method with the ValidationResult, where I can give the member names. So now, the attributes look like this, but the error still goes to key of string.Empty, not the actual members!

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class PropertiesMustMatchAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "'{0}' and '{1}' do not match.";
    private readonly object _typeId = new object();

    public PropertiesMustMatchAttribute(string originalProperty, string confirmProperty)
        : base(_defaultErrorMessage)
    {
        OriginalProperty = originalProperty;
        ConfirmProperty = confirmProperty;

    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value);
        object originalValue = properties.Find(OriginalProperty, true /* ignoreCase */).GetValue(value);
        object confirmValue = properties.Find(ConfirmProperty, true /* ignoreCase */).GetValue(value);
        if (Object.Equals(originalValue, confirmValue) == false)
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage, new[] { OriginalProperty, ConfirmProperty });
        else return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public string ConfirmProperty { get; private set; }
    public string OriginalProperty { get; private set; }

    public override object TypeId
    {
        get
        {
            return _typeId;
        }
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, ErrorMessageString,
            OriginalProperty, ConfirmProperty);
    }

}
```